# Inner join but I don't understand the foreign key bit with a nother table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables like so

Product Table:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| productID    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| manufacturer | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rating       | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| categoryID   | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Category Table:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| categoryID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| categoryName | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

User:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| userID    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| age       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| username  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Review:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| reviewID   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| reviewTime | date       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reviewData | mediumtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productID  | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| userID     | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I basically need a select statement that shows the following

```
reviewID - reviewTime - reviewData - product.name - category.name - user.firstname
```

I have come up with the following so far

```
SELECT r.reviewID, r.reviewTime, r.reviewData, p.name, u.firstname 
  FROM review r 
  INNER JOIN product p on p.productID = r.productID 
  INNER JOIN user u on u.userID = r.userID;
```

This gives me everything but the category name as thats where I am stuck.

The database is linked like this;

[image]

I just don't understand how to pass the categoryname from category table through to the review table

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT. More useful than a png

Comment: Ok thanks @Strawberry I will try to in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select r.reviewID, r.reviewTime, r.reviewData, p.name, u.firstname, c.categoryName
from review r
left join product p on p.productID = r.productID
left join user u on u.userID = r.userID
left join category c on c.categoryID = p.categoryID
```

Note: Based on your schema, I have used LEFT JOINs so that all reviews will get returned whether there is related data or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query:

```
SELECT r.reviewID, r.reviewTime, r.reviewData, p.name, u.firstname 
FROM review r 
    INNER JOIN product p on p.productID = r.productID 
    INNER JOIN user u on u.userID = r.userID;
```

Since you're already joining on the product table and the product table has a reference to `categoryID`, just add another join:

```
SELECT 
    r.reviewID, r.reviewTime, r.reviewData, p.name, u.firstname, c.categoryName  
FROM review r 
    INNER JOIN product p on p.productID = r.productID 
    INNER JOIN user u on u.userID = r.userID;
    INNER JOIN category c ON c.categoryID = p.categoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `INNER JOIN category c on c.categoryID = p.categoryID`

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining category table add

```
Join category c on c.categoryID = p.categoryID
```

And add select

```
 c.name
```

Also change joins to left join only if it is possible that any link between tables does not exists.